# How to preserve metadata of all the files and folders document files while downloading from sharepoint online/onPremise?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to download all the document files from sharepoint online/onprem to my computer programmatically.

Actual Result: I can able to download the files/folders from sharepoint online/onPrem, but the meta data is being update to the current date( for e.g.created and Modified dates were showing with the date and timestamp when this activity was done).

Expected Result - It should preserve the original meta data of all the files and folders when it created and modified.

Answer (score 0):

if You switch to classic UI view of the library and using IE web browser You should be able to use 'Open in explorer' option in the ribbon in the library tab. That way You will get the files directly from SP with windows folder explorer and the modified and created dates should be preserved.

I Hope this will be of any help

Comment: Can this be made to generate a zip file the way the Download feature of SharePoint does?